# Increase stack size on Windows cmd MinGW C++

Tags: arrays, windows, stack, mingw

I'm running code on my 64 bit Windows 8 system with 8 GB RAM, given to me for my project, involving essentially three dimensional matrices, and these matrices are huge (20x20x60000). After I compile the code in the Linux terminal I run:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

and then I can execute the programme as expected.

On my Windows command prompt I am able to use the command:

```
g++ -I"C:\gsl" -L"C:\gsl" main.cp -o main.exe -lgsl -lgslcblas -Wall -lm
```

But gives me an error:

```
main.cp:141:6: error: total size of local objects too large
void TrajectoryAdd(void *p, double time)
```

The above command works perfectly when I reduce the size of the matrix and so I'm assuming that the stack size is not big enough. So I've been trying to use:

```
g++ -Wl,--stack,46777216
```

But that returns:

```
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried variations of this command as suggested on other posts, but that doesn't seem to work, that is,

```
g++ -Wl,--stack,46777216 -o -I"C:\gsl" -L"C:\gsl" main.cp -o main.exe -lgsl -lgslcblas -Wall -lm
```

For some slightly smaller matrices I have been able to compile, but when I run the executable I get a Windows error: Main.exe has stopped working.

I'm a beginner in C++, and so I will not be able to commit to the other solution of modifying the source code.

Comment: Make sure you're using the MinGW-w64 port of GCC, as the original MinGW port doesn't support 64-bit code. The "total size of local objects too large" error message suggests that you're trying to allocate more than can possibly fit on the stack no matter what set the stack size to.

Comment: Objects that big shouldn't be on the stack in the first place.  Either make it `static` or allocate it dynamically.